# Is it posssible to execute an SQL Server procedure via email?

Tags: sql-server, email

Currently I have a procedure that displays disk information by sending an email to the user.

I'd like to create a link within the email that when clicked, executes a different procedure stored on that server.

Is this possible to do in SQL Server?

Would I have to perhaps pass an osql command, or something of that sort?

Comment: Does you SQL server have the ability to receive emails and process them? Sending emails is easy. Teaching it to fetch and read them is a whole other matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install IIS on that server, or on another one, and then put a small web application in it that connects to SQL Server and runs the procedure when invoked. So you could have a URL like http://your.sql.server/YourApp.aspx (or `.asp`, or `.php`... ASP.NET is probably the easiest approach) that runs the procedure when clicked.

Of course, while it would be quite easy to throw in such a quick-and-dirty solution, a proper one would require a lot more care (just think about user authentication).